# Is there a SQL query where it can retrieve data only those which contains a hyphen after the second letter?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute a SQL query which returns to me data from a column all those which contains a hyphen after their second letter.

Basically I have column which contains strings in the form of "BC-123456-1" but inbetween them I have other strings like NULL(as a string not type) and other junk strings

My current query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM Table WHERE constraint IS NULL AND column IS NOT NULL
```

So is there some way I can filter out those data which don't fit my pattern?

Comment: `substring(column, 2, 1) = '-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM Table WHERE constraint IS NULL AND column IS NOT NULL AND 
column LIKE '__-%'
```

The "__" underscore will allow any 2 characters followed by a hyphen and "%" will allow any number of characters after it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM Table WHERE constraint IS NULL AND IFNULL(column,'') LIKE '__-%';
```

**Explanation**

1) `IFNULL` checks if column and then i have replaced the null value with `''`

2) In like clause i have kept 2 underscore `__` a underscore means a single character. so i have put 2 underscore.